# Relation does not exist while scanning schema

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, identifier

My Postgres database is getting slow while executing some function. But another database of identical design and with more data is much faster than the first one. I have recently migrated data from MS SQL to PostgreSQL. So I have checked if there is any problem from following queries:

```
SELECT
  relname                                               AS TableName,
  to_char(seq_scan, '999,999,999,999')                  AS TotalSeqScan,
  to_char(idx_scan, '999,999,999,999')                  AS TotalIndexScan,
  to_char(n_live_tup, '999,999,999,999')                AS TableRows,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relname :: regclass)) AS TableSize
FROM pg_stat_all_tables
WHERE schemaname = 'loan'
      AND 50 * seq_scan > idx_scan -- more then 2%
      AND n_live_tup > 10000
      AND pg_relation_size(relname :: regclass) > 5000000
ORDER BY relname ASC;
```

And I got the result:

> ```
> ERROR:  relation "mv_transaction_view" does not exist
> SQL state: 42P01
> ```

What is the solution for this? I have a materialized view named `mv_transaction_view`.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102624/110455

Answer (score 1):

Use **`relid`** instead of **`relname`**:

```
SELECT relname                                 AS tablename
     , to_char(seq_scan  , '999,999,999,999')  AS total_seqscan
     , to_char(idx_scan  , '999,999,999,999')  AS total_indexscan
     , to_char(n_live_tup, '999,999,999,999')  AS tablerows
     , pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relid)) AS tablesize
FROM   pg_stat_all_tables
WHERE  schemaname = 'loan'
AND    50 * seq_scan > COALESCE(idx_scan, 0) -- more then 2%
AND    n_live_tup > 10000
AND    pg_relation_size(relid) > 5000000;
```

#### Why?

Assuming you do not have the schema `loan` in your **`search_path`**, Postgres is unable to resolve the cast `mv_transaction_view::regclass` - looking up unqualified tablenames only in the schemas listed in the current `search_path`. Hence the error:

> ```
>  ERROR: relation "mv_transaction_view" does not exist
> ```

Materialized views are also listed among "tables" in the view `pg_stat_all_tables`, that's not the problem.

The missing schema in the `search_path` is also ***not*** the problem. Just the messenger in a manner of speaking. The problem is a **bug in your query**. Imagine a table `loan.tbl` and a `search_path` of `public, loan`. Your query would just work fine. Or would it?
Now imagine an innocent (or malevolent) user creating a table `public.tbl`. Then you run your query again ...

Using `relid` instead is the safe solution. You don't even need to cast since that's the `OID of a table`, exactly what `pg_relation_size()` expects. (The cast `oid` -> `regclass` is implicit.)

Details:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089729/939860)
- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)

Also note `COALESCE(idx_scan, 0)`:
`idx_scan` can be `NULL`, and you wouldn't wanna miss tables with all sequential scans.

- The manual on [`pg_stat_all_tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ALL-TABLES-VIEW).